# Resize image with SimpleImage and send it directly to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

After upload images i resize them using [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) and send to AWS S3. Today i am saving the images in local disk, sending to S3 and then delete the local files. I would like skip to step do save and delete the local files.

I tried:

```
$S3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key'    => 'myfile.jpeg',
    'Body'   => (new SimpleImage('/path/to/myfile.jpeg'))
                    ->bestFit(
                        800,
                        600
                    )->toString();
]);
```

The file is sended, but when i access its public URL at AWS S3, the browser tries to download the file and don't show it.

Any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the object public and add ContentType

```
$S3->putObject([
    'Bucket'      => 'mybucket',
    'Key'         => 'myfile.jpeg',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',     // <-- add this line
    'Body'        => (new SimpleImage('/path/to/myfile.jpeg'))
                        ->bestFit(
                            800,
                            600
                      )->toString();
]);
```

Comment: The bucket has a public policy, so all files are public by default

Comment: try to add 'ContentType' => 'image', also, maybe it helps... 
when you see the image properties onto S3 does it say it's public?
also, try to include the path into a html page and see if the image is displayed... I had this problems when I accessed the image via S3 and it got downloaded but it was perfectly displayed into the browser

Comment: Adding the 'ContentType' it works fine, thanks! Please update your answer, so i will accept it.